# python str != str not gives expected results

Tags: python

I have two data files:

file1 (815 lines):

```
 1    2    3     a 
 2    3    3     b
 1    2    2     b
```

file2 (1200 lines):

```
 2    5     5    a
 2    1     1    b
 1    2     2    c
```

What I want in output is the following:

```
  1    2     2    c
```

This is supposed to be the line from file2 which differs in the last column from file1 (you will notice that in the first two lines the last column is identical in both files); no matter what values first three columns contain, if the last column is unique, print that line.

I am naively trying to do it with the following (python3) code but unsuccessful, so far, please guide. Thanks

```
with open(file1,'rU') as ij:
    for i in ij:
        i = i.rstrip().split('\t')
        with open(file2,'rU') as ji:
            for j in ji:
                j = j.rstrip().split('\t')
                if str(i[-1]) != str(j[-1]):
                    print(j)
```

With this method I am printing following:

```
2    3     3   b                                                                                                            
4    2     3   c
```

Comment: "but unsuccessful" How? It seems like you are checking all combinations of lines, not just lines that have the same number. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through the code line by line. Think a bit about the logic in your loop (and do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)).

Comment: What strings are not giving expected results when compared?

Comment: :) .... please use print statements ... put `printstr(i[-1]), str(j[-1])` .. ans see what are you comparing

Comment: This is problem with algorithm. Think about dictionaries from both files and printing value for keys with unique values.

Comment: Also, please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And then edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I think I understand what the Q meant to say; I changed the wording a bit, please consider voting to reopen now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with something like this:

```
with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2:
  for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
    if line1.split()[-1] != line2.split()[-1]:
      print(line2)
```

This assumes several things:

- The two files are to be compared line by line.
- File1 doesn't contain more or less lines than File2 (no inserted lines, not deleted lines, or the comparison will become out of sync).
- The columns can be found using `line.split()`, so the contents is whitespace-separated.

Comment: Thank you @Alfe for your response, the file1 has 825 lines and file2 has 1200 lines, is it a problem?

Comment: your method is also printing in the same manner as mine:                                         
     **1    2     2    c**          
     **1    2     3   c**                                                                                                             
     **4    2     3   c**

Comment: @user3698773 Sure, that is a problem.  What do you expect to happen in this case?  Shall the 375 lines which file2 has more be printed (because they do not have a counterpart in file1 and thus they are "not equal in the last column")?  That's not specified.